# Parquet Data timestamp columns INT96 not yet implemented in Druid Overlord Hadoop task

Tags: avro, emr, parquet, druid

**Context:**

I am able to submit a MapReduce job from druid overlord to an EMR. My Data source is in S3 in Parquet format. I have a timestamp column (INT96) in parquet data which is not supported in Avroschema.

Error is while parsing the timestamp

**Issue Stack trace is:**

```
Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: INT96 not yet implemented.
at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter$1.convertINT96(AvroSchemaConverter.java:279)
at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter$1.convertINT96(AvroSchemaConverter.java:264)
at org.apache.parquet.schema.PrimitiveType$PrimitiveTypeName$7.convert(PrimitiveType.java:223)
```

**Environment:**

```
Druid version: 0.11
EMR version : emr-5.11.0
Hadoop version: Amazon 2.7.3
```

**Druid input json**

```
{
  "type": "index_hadoop",
  "spec": {
    "ioConfig": {
      "type": "hadoop",
      "inputSpec": {
        "type": "static",
        "inputFormat": "io.druid.data.input.parquet.DruidParquetInputFormat",
        "paths": "s3://s3_path"
      }
    },
    "dataSchema": {
      "dataSource": "parquet_test1",
      "granularitySpec": {
        "type": "uniform",
        "segmentGranularity": "DAY",
        "queryGranularity": "ALL",
        "intervals": ["2017-08-01T00:00:00/2017-08-02T00:00:00"]
      },
      "parser": {
        "type": "parquet",
        "parseSpec": {
          "format": "timeAndDims",
          "timestampSpec": {
            "column": "t",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS zzz"            
          },
          "dimensionsSpec": {
            "dimensions": [
              "dim1","dim2","dim3"
            ],
            "dimensionExclusions": [],
            "spatialDimensions": []
          }
        }
      },
      "metricsSpec": [{
        "type": "count",
        "name": "count"
      },{
          "type" : "count",
          "name" : "pid",
          "fieldName" : "pid"
        }]
    },
    "tuningConfig": {
      "type": "hadoop",
      "partitionsSpec": {
        "targetPartitionSize": 5000000
      },
      "jobProperties" : {
        "mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first": "true",
        "fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId" : "KEYID",
        "fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey" : "AccessKey",
        "fs.s3.impl" : "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem",
        "fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId" : "KEYID",
        "fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey" : "AccessKey",
        "fs.s3n.impl" : "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem",
        "io.compression.codecs" : "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec"
      },
      "leaveIntermediate": true
    }
  }, "hadoopDependencyCoordinates": ["org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.7.3", "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3", "com.hadoop.gplcompression:hadoop-lzo:0.4.20"]
}
```

**Possible solution**

```
 1. Save the data in parquet efficiently instead of transforming in Avro to remove the dependencies.

 2. Fixing AvroSchema to support INT96 timestamp format of Parquet.
```

Comment: I saw the post that discusses the issue 
    [Link]https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/parquet-dev/201607.mbox/%3COF5EA1EF03.E9389FB2-ON65257FE8.003786AC-65257FE8.0038938D@notes.na.collabserv.com%3E


Any ideas if this is in the roadmap or any other solution possible.

Answer (score 0):

Druid from versions **0.17.0 and above** supports Parquet INT96 type using the **Parquet Hadoop Parser**.

> The Parquet Hadoop Parser supports int96 Parquet values, while the Parquet Avro Hadoop Parser does not. There may also be some subtle differences in the behavior of JSON path expression evaluation of flattenSpec.

https://druid.apache.org/docs/0.17.0/ingestion/data-formats.html#parquet-hadoop-parser