# Converting Parquet to avro throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: INT96 not yet implemented error

Tags: java, avro, parquet, parquet-mr

I am trying to convert a parquet file to avro but throwing "INT96 not yet implemented"

Could you please suggest any solution for this

```
Parquet parquet = ParquetReaderUtils.getParquetData("000001_0");
            MessageType messageType = new MessageType("org.apache.parquet.avro.myrecord",parquet.getSchema());  
            AvroSchemaConverter avroSchemaConverter = new AvroSchemaConverter(new Configuration(false));
            Schema convertedAvroSchema = avroSchemaConverter.convert(messageType);
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: INT96
>   not yet implemented.  at
>   org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter$1.convertINT96(AvroSchemaConverter.java:279)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter$1.convertINT96(AvroSchemaConverter.java:264)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.schema.PrimitiveType$PrimitiveTypeName$7.convert(PrimitiveType.java:297)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter.convertField(AvroSchemaConverter.java:263)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter.convertFields(AvroSchemaConverter.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter.convert(AvroSchemaConverter.java:231)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parquet Data *timestamp* columns INT96 not yet implemented in Druid Overlord Hadoop task](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48366196/5221149)

Comment: *FYI:* Error text has been [changed](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/commit/6901a2040848c6b37fa61f4b0a76246445f396db) to `INT96 not implemented and is deprecated` ([PARQUET-1480](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1480))

Comment: What does `parquet.getSchema()` contain? Is there a chance to come up with an explicit schema that would limit the size of the field to something Avro understands?