# Unable to read date format columns (int96 type) from avro-parquet schema in Apache Beam

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am facing the following exception when reading the parquet file having **date** column. I am using **beam-sdks-java-io* 2.11.0 and parquet*-1.10**
please, help me for the same.

Thank You in advance.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: INT96 not yet implemented.
    at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter$1.convertINT96(AvroSchemaConverter.java:279)
    at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter$1.convertINT96(AvroSchemaConverter.java:264)
    at org.apache.parquet.schema.PrimitiveType$PrimitiveTypeName$7.convert(PrimitiveType.java:297)
    at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter.convertField(AvroSchemaConverter.java:263)
    at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter.convertFields(AvroSchemaConverter.java:241)
    at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter.convert(AvroSchemaConverter.java:231)
    at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroReadSupport.prepareForRead(AvroReadSupport.java:130)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.initialize(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:183)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader.initReader(ParquetReader.java:156)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader.read(ParquetReader.java:135)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.parquet.ParquetIO$ReadFiles$ReadFn.processElement(ParquetIO.java:221)
```

Comment: This is the expected behavior as per the implementation `"org/apache/parquet/avro/AvroSchemaConverter.java":

            public Schema convertINT96(PrimitiveTypeName 
primitiveTypeName) {
              throw new IllegalArgumentException("INT96 not yet 
implemented.");`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48366196/parquet-data-timestamp-columns-int96-not-yet-implemented-in-druid-overlord-hadoo

Answer (score 3):

Parquet **INT96** type is "deprecated" but the `parquet-avro` library added a property in the **1.12.0** release to allow customers with old large datasets to be able to reprocess it again and convert into a supported type (**fixed 12 byte array**).[1]

You could pass the `parquet.avro.readInt96AsFixed` property with the value `"true"`. [2]

If you are using ParquetIO from Beam:

```
    PCollection<GenericRecord> records =
        pipeline.apply(ParquetIO.read(SCHEMA).from(options.getMyParquetFilesLocation())
            .withConfiguration(Map.of("parquet.avro.readInt96AsFixed", "true")));
```

[1] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1928

[2] https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-avro

Answer (score 0):

As per [Parquet-Avro](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.parquet/parquet-avro/latest/org/apache/parquet/avro/package-summary.html) documentation int96 (parquet type) is not supported in Avro type mapping.